# How do i fix npm run <script> error problem

Tags: package.json

After i added scripts to my **package.json** file which is shown below.

```
{   
"name": "indecision-app",
"version": "1.0.0",   
"main":"index.js",   
"author": "hendrx",   
"license": "MIT",   
"scripts": {
     "serve": "live-server public/"   
},   
"dependencies": {
     "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
     "babel-preset-env": "1.5.2",
     "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "live-server": "^1.2.1"   
},   
"devDependencies": {} 
}
```

i tried to run

> npm run serve

to start live-server in the public folder. But i get error to this log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\AKA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.6.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~preserve: indecision-app@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: indecision-app@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: PATH: C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\AKA\Desktop\react-course-project\indecision-app\node_modules\.bin;C:\Ruby25-x64\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;"C:\WINDOWS\system32;";C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
9 verbose lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: CWD: C:\Users\AKA\Desktop\react-course-project\indecision-app
10 silly lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'live-server public/' ]
11 silly lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle indecision-app@1.0.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: indecision-app@1.0.0 serve: `live-server public/`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid indecision-app@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\AKA\Desktop\react-course-project\indecision-app
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\AKA\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v12.6.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error indecision-app@1.0.0 serve: `live-server public/`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the indecision-app@1.0.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Please i don't know what's wrong here and i don't want to install **live-server** as a global dependency.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your node version. Try switching it to more stable version like 10.16.0

Comment: my node version is ` v12.6.0  ` is it not stable?

Comment: v12.6.0 is not yet Long Term Supported. 10.16.0 is the last LTS.
https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: Ok so i have to put my node version back to 10.16.0?

Comment: Yes. It might solve your porblem.

Comment: Ok thanks, do you know of a command i can run to get that done? i'm on windows 10

Comment: Uninstall your nodejs first. Like you uninstall a software from windows. Then install the 10.16.0 version from https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: ok i just did that and my node and npm versions are node -v 10.16.0 npm -v
6.10.2 is this ok

Comment: i tried to run **npm run serve** command again but the same error message  i got before      Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit

Comment: Delete the node_modules folder located at %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
Also delete the npm cache folder generally located at %AppData%/npm-cache
Then **npm install** in your project root folder.

Comment: not working after deleting those and run npm install and npm run serve give same error